# Crontab Fail. Node Script Fails When Run From Outside Directory

Tags: node.js, cron, dotenv

I'm trying to run a NodeJs script every 5 minutes using Crontab, which is currently failing.

I've noticed that when I run my script from inside the folder, it works fine. But when I try to run the script from outside the folder it fails.. it doesn't appear to pick up the .env parameters?

crontab -e
*/5 * * * * node ~/ls-mongo/updateItems.js

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because node interpreter is not able to find any installed npm dependencies, since it is scanning the folder, you are running the command in, for them. You can cd into the folder and then run the script:

```
cd ~/ls-mongo && crontab -e */5 * * * * node updateItems.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this before, but adding the below to the top of the file works.

process.chdir(__dirname);